# Please Identify this frame FAKE BMC?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

[image]

hi! I bought this bike as a BMC ALR one ~2016 model year. later I've realised that it's not BMC. The frame does not have BMC features. and have some that BMC never had on its bikes like this:
[image]
Also, there are some specific details:
[image]
specific shape of chain stay:
[image]
and frame have a serial number on its bracket bottom

> 0127280
>
> KG00503

I spent several days to find what it is and I'm out of ideas. I suppose it can be some Chinese noname frame as well.
[image]

Comment: It may not be authentic BMC, but it's still a bike.  If it works, and fits you then keep on riding it.

Comment: @Criggie thanks for an opinion. i'm totaly fine with this frame i ride it 2 seasons. last season i set fulcrum 5 on it and this one change old sora for 105 r7000. i think to ride at least one more season before move to something up in class. maybe it will be real BMC :)
but for now i'm just super curious about whit i'm riding on

Comment: so. that's focus izalco ltd 2006

Comment: if you've identified it, do post that as an answer in the box below.   Helps with searches if the question has a confirmed answer.